# problem with commitEditingStyle -to delete cell in the table

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

i have one section table which contain the section and i want to delete the perticular cell swap and delete this cell and remove that cell from table and also remove from the array.

and how to animate that when the delete the cell.

for that i code below but which is not working please help to do this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.reports removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tbl reloadData];
            [tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] 
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];    



    }   
}
```

After much more R&D then i build up new code and which is successfully Run

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    [[[self.reports objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"events"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target: self selector: @selector(tableReload) userInfo: nil repeats: NO]; 
}
```

}

```
-(void)tableReload{
    [tbl reloadData];  }
```

Comment: can you share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: i create the custom cell and that put it into table

Comment: i just wanted to see how you are assigning text to the cell so as to check if u are deleting the correct array object. You mentioned sectioned tableview which means you need to chekc both row and section of indexpath but you were checking only row. Anyways, good that ur problem is solved now

Comment: Actuly i solve this problem which gives above thax to help me.

Comment: try this `[tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];` than triggering NSTimer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you should not `Reload table` before  deleting row from table. Secondly, in your case you have multiple sections and multiple rows in that section, I guess. So, your

```
[tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] 
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

won't work.
Deleting object from array will work. You don't have to delete row from your table. Just reload table :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.reports removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tbl reloadData];
}
```

But do take care that you are putting the correct indexNumber.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  [[[self.reports objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"events"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
 
}

Answer (score 2):

You are not nil terminating your NSArray and that is why the row isn't being deleted from your Table View.

The following line:

```
[tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Should actually be:

```
[tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Notice the nil after IndexPath. arrayWithObjects should be a nil terminated list of Objects

Comment: After the some sort of the R&D and develop below code which is successfully run.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  [[[self.reports objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"events"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [tbl deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
 
}