# App crashing on reloadData method of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app is crashing after calling method of `[tableView reloadData]` table view. This is occurring on after deleting a single row of tableview(with table view default deleting behavior) and call `[tableView reloadData]` and then right after this delegate `numberOfSectionsInTableView`app gets crash and show me crash message `[UITableViewCell _setDeleteAnimationInProgress : ] : message sent to deallocated instance`, I googled but couldn't able to get healthy response. So kindly help to find out this issue if any one face this sort of crash. Here below is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0)
        return [[dbSingleton sharedInstance] get_players_count];
    else if(section==1)
        return 0;
}

- (NSString )tableView:(UITableView )tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section==0)
        return @"Player Detail";
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView )tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath )indexPath{
    if(indexPath.section==1)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView )tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath )indexPath{
    return 44;
}
```

Looking for response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you updating the data source?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I would say that [[dbSingleton sharedInstance] get_players_count] is not being updated when you delete the row through your tableView delegate method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. What I was doing wrong is that I am calling method `reloadData` on `commitEditingStyle`, its mean reloading data before deleting row, As mention in answer of [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857711/problem-with-commiteditingstyle-to-delete-cell-in-the-table). I hope this will help others as well. 
Thanks for your participations.

Answer (score -1):

[tableView Reload] produces crash then it is pretty sure that there is problem in datasource so i think add breakpoint in tableview section and check whether you are updating your datasource properly otherwise show the complete crash message.

Comment: @answered, Thanks for answer but I found solution kindly look into my answer.